# sum of $f(x)$ being less than integral

Tags: integration, summation, induction

I have to prove that:
$$
\quad \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} j \ln(j) \leq \int_{1}^{n} x \ln(x) \ \mathrm{d}x
$$
I am wondering whether inductive prove is possible, I evaluated integral and got closed formula and then started induction on $n$, however inductive step seems hard to prove for me.

$$
\text{Inductive Hypothesis:} \quad \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} j \ln(j) \leq \int_{1}^{k} x \ln(x) \ \mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: Hint (I haven't tried). Think of the left hand side as an approximation of the right hand side.

Comment: does that involve inductive proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively notice that

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\bigl(x\ln x\bigr)=\ln x+1>0$$

for all $x>\frac{1}{e}$, meaning that $x\mapsto x\ln x$ is strictly increasing on $\left(\frac{1}{e},\infty\right)$, so

\begin{align*}
\int_1^nx\ln x\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\int_j^{j+1}x\ln x\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&\geq\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\int_j^{j+1}j\ln j\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\ln j.
\end{align*}

---

We can use the same idea to do an inductive proof. The base case $n=1$ is trivial, as both sides are $0$. Suppose now that the inequality holds for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. Then, since $x\mapsto x\ln x$ is increasing on $[n,n+1]$,

\begin{align*}
\int_1^{n+1}x\ln x\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_1^nx\ln x\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_n^{n+1}x\ln x\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&\geq\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\ln j+\int_n^{n+1}x\ln x\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&\geq\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\ln j+\int_n^{n+1}n\ln n\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\ln j+n\ln n \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^nj\ln j,
\end{align*}

from which the result follows.

Comment: ooh, changing xln(x) in integration with nln(n) was great trick, I was thinking about using strictly increasing property of the function somehow, which I couldn't, also my problem was that I evaluated integral and started induction on closed formula, instead of integral alone. anyway thanks, great answer. helped a lot. but I think it should also be possible to induct on closed formula(after evaluating integral directly).

Comment: also can you try inductive proof after evaluating integral, so remove integral and change it with closed formula.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$f(x)
=x\ln(x)$
satisfies
$f'(x)
=\ln(x)+1
\gt 0
$
for $x > 1/e$.

More generally,
if $f'(x) > 0$ then
$f(x)
\lt \int_x^{x+1} f(t) dt
$
because

$\begin{array}\\
\int_x^{x+1} f(t) dt-f(x)
&=\int_x^{x+1} (f(t)-f(x) dt\\
&\gt 0\\
\end{array}
$

since
$f(t)>f(x)$ for
$x < t \le x+1$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} f(j)
&\lt \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \int_j^{j+1} f(t)dt\\
&=\int_1^n f(t) dt\\
\end{array}
$

This can be converted
to an inductive proof by using
the base case
$(n=2)$
$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} f(j)
\lt \int_1^n f(t) dt
$
and
$f(n)
\lt  \int_n^{n+1} f(t) dt
$.

Also note that
$f(x+1)
\gt \int_x^{x+1} f(t) dt
$
so that
$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} f(j+1)
\gt \int_1^n f(t) dt
$.

The inequalities are reversed if
$f'(x) < 0$.

Comment: is there way to inductively prove the same answer after evaluating integral.

Comment: I don't think so. You need to be able to compare $f(j)$ with $\int_j^{j+1} f(t) dt$. Also, there may not be a simple formula for the integral, and this shows that one is not needed.